# Core Data check if is already saved, Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

im building app where random quote from plist is displaying and you can save it to favorites(core data), I want to check if my random generated quote already exists in core data or no, I just want to change save button if its already saved

Quote.swift:

```
var quotesPlist: NSArray! = []

override func awakeFromNib() {
    loadQuote()
}

func loadQuote(){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("quotesList", ofType: "plist")
    quotesPlist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
    quoteLbl.text = quotesPlist[Int(randomNumber())] as? String
}
```

SavedQuote properties:

```
@NSManaged var quote: String?
@NSManaged var creationDate: NSDate?
@NSManaged var uuid: String?
```

this is HomeVC:

```
 func createQuoteFromNib() -> QuoteView! {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("QuoteView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? QuoteView

}

@IBAction func saveACTION(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if let label = currentQuote.quoteLbl.text where label != "" {

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("SavedQuotes", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        let quote = SavedQuotes(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        quote.quote = currentQuote.quoteLbl.text
        quote.creationDate = NSDate()
        quote.uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
        context.insertObject(quote)


        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

this is my FavoritesVC:

```
 var quotesArray = [SavedQuotes]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func fetchAndSetResults(){
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SavedQuotes")
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        quotesArray = results as! [SavedQuotes]
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear how you're generating this new quote. At minimum you need to use a fetch request to check if the quote exists before you call `insertIntoManagedObjectContext`. You can do that as soon as the quote exists and you're configuring the view (with the quote text and the save button).

Your fetch request uses a simple predicate to check for a quote with matching `quote` text.

You already have a fetch request to list all the quotes, so all you need to add to that for the check is a predicate with format `"quote = %@"` and check the count of the results (which should always be either 0 or 1 (meaning save and don't save respectively).